# Does $ \arg \min_{x_{2n}} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left( {s}_{i} - x_{2n} \right)^{2n} $, for $n>1$, have a name and/or application?

Tags: means, median

Given a list of $N$ real numbers $s_i$:

the *median* $x_0$ is

$$ \arg \min_{x_0} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left| {s}_{i} - x_0 \right| $$

the *mean* $x_2$ is

$$ \arg \min_{x_2} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left( {s}_{i} - x_2 \right)^2 $$

What about $x_4$?

$$ \arg \min_{x_4} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left( {s}_{i} - x_4 \right)^4 $$

does have it a name?

And what about the generic $x_{2n}$

$$ \arg \min_{x_{2n}} \sum_{i = 1}^{N} \left( {s}_{i} - x_{2n} \right)^{2n} $$

Are there any known application for $n>1$?

Answer (score 2):

They are [partial moments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)#Partial_moments) with respect to the minimizing reference point of an un-normalized uniformly distributed probability function.
From wikipedia:
$$\mu_n^-(r) + \mu_n^+(r)$$

$$r_o = \min_{r}\left\{\int_{-\infty}^\infty (r-x)^n f(x)dx\right\}$$

Where $f(x)$ is uniform discrete probability density $[0,N]$. (Since we are working with continuous case and integral instead of sum this is actually a sequence of [Paul Dirac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Dirac)'s [delta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) at integer values.)

---

**Edit** I first misread as $(x_k-i)^k$, that would have given the uniform discrete distribution mentioned above. Now what instead happens is we have sum of Dirac distributions like this: $$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^N \delta(x-s_i)$$

Comment: No wait, this ain't right. I will try to fix it. Ok, that should fix it, I think.